# C# Запись в файл без .NET Framework

Tags: c#

Написал простое приложения для создания текстового файла с использованием метода WriteAllText, но программа не работает без установленной .NET

Есть ли в C# какие-нибудь методы чтобы скомпилированная программа работала в чистой Windows XP?

Comment: Ага, метод называется "написание на Си".

Comment: То есть C# без .NET вообще не может? И все функции хранятся в ней?

Comment: A Win XP с сервиспаками или нет?

Comment: И еще - какую версию .Net использовали?

Comment: В получающемся EXE-файле практически нет кода, исполняющегося на реальном процессоре. Там куча хитромудрых структур и байт-кода, который дергает внешние функции. Загрузчик, парсер структур, интерпретатор байт-кода и находятся в .NET-фреймворке. В итоге сотня Мб ненужных данных для Hello World.

Comment: Ella Svetlaya, у меня XP SP3, а .Net несколько разных версий стоит

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, тогда вопрос на каком языке лучше написать, чтобы программа работала на чистой винде и желательно без сервис паков?

Comment: @MyNick С/С++ с использованием WinAPI

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, Благодарю.

Comment: На XP SP3 уже есть .NET v2.0. Просто откомпилируйте свой проект под .Net 2.0 и всё.

Comment: Что значит "чистая винда"?! Начиная с Win7 .Net уже предустановлен, так что можно смело писать на C#.

Comment: Даже без сервис-паков на ХР должен работать вот этот код - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.71).aspx собранный ессна с целевой версией 1.1

Answer (score 6):

Практически все Windows системы содержат определенные версии .NET:

> #### XP
>
> - <kbd>.NET v1.0</kbd>  -- Сервис пак 1
> - <kbd>.NET v2.0</kbd>  -- Сервис пак 2 & 3
>
> #### Vista
>
> - <kbd>.NET v3.0</kbd>  -- Все сервис паки
>
> #### Windows 7
>
> - <kbd>.NET v3.5</kbd>
>
> #### Windows 8
>
> - <kbd>.NET v4.0</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd>
>
> #### Windows 8.1
>
> - <kbd>.Net v4.5</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd>
>
> #### Windows 10
>
> - <kbd>.Net v4.6</kbd> + <kbd>Metro UI</kbd> + <kbd>Universal Apps</kbd>
>
> #### Note:
>
> Если включены обновления, то с апдейтами прилетает еще и <kbd>.NET v4.6</kbd>

Если код не сильно привязан к последней версии .Net, то задайте в настройках проекта в Visual Studio нужную (например, более старшую) версию Framework и перекомпилируйте проект.

Также можно использовать сторонне ПО, например - `Turbo Studio` - позволяет запускать в системе .Net-приложения без установленного .Net FrameWork.

Также, как вариант, можно сконвертировать свой C# код в код C++ (либо вручную, либо с использованием конвертеров, например от Tangible Software Solutions или MakeSharpPwn (C# To Native C++ Converter)).

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ мне помог, но похоже информация не совсем верная - Win XP (все редакции, кроме Media Center Edition) не содержат .NET Framework, но она распространяется на установочном диске. Сейчас откомпилировал проект под .Net 2.0 и запустил на XP SP2 - не работает,- поставил .Net 2.0 и программа запустилась.

Comment: @MyNick попробуйте скомпилировать под версию 1.